# Trouble with SIGINT signal handling after calling ruby_init() in a C++ program

Tags: c++, ruby, embed, sigint

I'm currently working on a C++ program that embeds the Ruby interpreter using **ruby_init()**. However, I've noticed that after calling **ruby_init()**, the **SIGINT** (**Ctrl+C**) signal doesn't seem to work as expected within my program.

When **Ctrl+C** is pressed, the application does not close. It's only when I call **ruby_finalize()** that the **SIGINT** signal starts working again, and the application closes when **Ctrl+C** is pressed.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <ruby.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // SIGINT signal works at this point

  // Initialize the Ruby interpreter
  ruby_init();

  // SIGINT signal stops working after this point

  while (isOpen) {
    // Code that interacts with Ruby
  }

  // Close the Ruby interpreter
  ruby_finalize();

  // SIGINT starts working again

  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand why the **SIGINT** signal is not being captured and handled correctly when Ruby is embedded. Any insights into what might be causing this behavior and how to address it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

**Edit:**

I've attempted to capture the signal within the Ruby interpreter, but it's not receiving the interrupt signal. I've tried the following:

`rb_eval_string("Signal.trap('INT') { puts 'interrupt signal received' }");`

Comment: I suspect `ruby_init` itself is capturing the **SIGINT** and handling it correctly.

Comment: Me too, I'm trying to handle it with Signal.trap('INT') but I couldn't make it work yet.

Comment: So it neither works inside your C program, nor inside Ruby?

Comment: That's it, unless I'm doing something wrong, I tried this and it didn't work
`rb_eval_string("Signal.trap('INT') { puts 'interrupt signal received' }");`

I thought maybe the ruby interpreter was blocking the I/O so I moved it to another thread but that didn't solve it either

Comment: The relevant `rb_eval_string("Signal.trap('INT') { puts 'interrupt signal received' }");` is missing from your question.

Comment: I have already updated it. I wasn't sure if it wasn't working when I wrote the question; that's why I didn't add it before. You don't need to vote to close the question because of that. This doesn't help at all.

Comment: Can you add more to show how you're compiling the program to run it?